# iPad - General Network->What is the UI control?

Tags: ipad

In the below image, what is the UI control used to create the "Other Network" dialog? We need to create a similar non-full-screen popup.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a UIModalPresentationFormSheet.

From Apple's UIViewController documentation reference

> UIModalPresentationFormSheet
>   The width and height of the presented view are smaller than those of the screen and the view is centered on the screen. If the device is in a landscape orientation and the keyboard is visible, the position of the view is adjusted upward so that the view remains visible. All uncovered areas are dimmed to prevent the user from interacting with them.
>   Available in iOS 3.2 and later.
>   Declared in UIViewController.h.

See this article for an example [Display a view using modalPresentationStyle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694332/display-a-view-using-modalpresentationstyle)

Answer (score 0):

It should be a view controller presented modally using `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` as its `modalPresentationStyle`.